# Can I travel on recently issued visa on my cancelled unexpired passport, where I also have new passport?

Tags: visas

I have a cancelled passport (which was valid until 2020), and I also have a new passport valid until 2027, as I have applied for a new passport due to lack of pages.

Recently, I have received a visa for Oman, with my cancelled passport details on it. Can I travel on such a visa with my old passport details?

Comment: In general, yes, but I do not know whether Oman is an exception.

Comment: China for instance clearly states their Visa is still valid in an expired/cancelled Passport but you must present *both* at the border.

Comment: Virtually all countries allow this (Australia being the only exception I can think of).